# Protractor switching to elements within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, protractor

I want to access the elements inside an iFrame, and send keys to the email field:

```
  <iframe src=".." name="injectedLogin" title="Login">
   <body>
    <section id="login">
     <form action="/signin" method="post">
        <input id="email" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
      </div>
    </form>
   </section>
  </body>
 </iframe>
```

The following line of code previously worked:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(0);
```

However, recently the test case has been failing and the elements within the iFrame are not interacted with.

I have tried other solutions, such as:

```
browser.switchTo().frame('iframe[name="injectedUl"]');
```

and using window handles instead, however no solutions that I have come across online have worked.

I am using Protractor version 5.1.1.

Does anyone have a solution, or explanation as to why this may no longer work?

Comment: Share the html code for `iframe`

Comment: Thanks @KishanPatel - I have added the HTML.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Comment: No, unfortunately the page that I'm working with cannot be loaded directly through a url.